# No access to UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I am setting an UILabel inside of the cellForRowAtIndexPath method and when the user changes the text, the label should change. But even it is not nil, it doesn't change.

```
@property UILabel *myLabel;

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
     self.myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, textView.frame.size.width, 37)];
     self.myLabel.text = @"Old Text";
}

- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
     self.myLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
     self.myLabel.text = @"New Text";
}
```

I found a solution where some people are changing the UILabel in the main thread but that's not working for me.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       // Do in main thread
});
```

Comment: The code you posted can possibly work. Your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` isn't dequeuing a cell or creating a new cell, and doesn't return a cell. It doesn't attach the label you created to a cell. Post the whole `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, as well as info about the `self.myLabel` property you're using, if you want help.

Comment: Your are not creating a new cell. Everytime cellForRowAtIndexPath is called, your label is initialised again and the "old Text" is assigned again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the label of a cell that's on-screen "on the fly" then you need a way to reach the label.

What I usually do is to create a template for the cell in IB, define a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell`, and set the cell's class to that custom subclass. Then I connect outlets between the cell and all the custom fields I've created.

In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, I dequeue a cell and cast it to my custom type. Then I reference the fields in the cell through the cell, e.g.

`cell.myLabel`.

If you add a new field to your cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you have a couple of problems. First, you need to make sure you don't add another copy of that new field when you recycle the cell. Second, you need a way to get to the field if you want to modify it, as in your question. There are ways to deal with these problems, but the approach I outlined above is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Duncan, I'm sorry, here is the rest of the cellForRowAtIndexPath. I thought it could not be a problem of reusing the cell as I'm not scrolling so the cell should not be recreated.

```
@property NSString *textField_1;
@property NSString *textField_2;
// ...
@property UILabel *myLabel;

@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    self.myLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.myLabel.text = @"New Text";
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    if(indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        float displayResolutionWidth = self.view.frame.size.width;
        UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, displayResolutionWidth - 165, 50)];
        textField.delegate = self;
        textField.tag = indexPath.row;
        textField.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

        UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, displayResolutionWidth - 90, 176)];
        textView.delegate = self;
        textView.tag = indexPath.row;
        textView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

        self.myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, textView.frame.size.width, 37)];
        self.myLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

        if(indexPath.row == 17)
        {
            cell.accessoryView = textView;
            [textView addSubview:self.myLabel];
        }
        else if (indexPath.row != 17)
        {
            cell.accessoryView = textField;
        }
        if (self.object)
        {
            if (indexPath.row == 0)
                textField.text = self.object.property_1;
            if (indexPath.row == 1)
                textField.text = self.object.property_2;
        }
        else if (!self.object)
        {
            if (indexPath.row == 0)
                textField.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"Placeholder_1", @"")
                                                                                  attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor greenColor]}];
            if (indexPath.row == 1)
                textField.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"Placeholder_2", @"")
                                                                                  attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor greenColor]}];
            if (indexPath.row == 17)
                self.myLabel.text = "Old Text";
        }
        if (indexPath.row != 17)
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = [self.arrayWithObjectData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
        else if (indexPath.row == 17)
        {
            UILabel *mylabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(16, 0, 150, 40)];
            mylabel.text = self.arrayWithObjectData[17];
            mylabel.textColor = [UIColor COLOR_TEXT];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:mylabel];
        }
    }
       return cell;
}

@end
```